# Step through disassembled i386 code (raw machine code - no headers of any kind)

Tags: gcc, assembly, ld, i386, linker-errors

I believe [this](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/qH5cmcYD/0) code to be i386 assembly.

How can I step through the code on on either a Mac, Linux or Windows? (or online if possible)

I assume I'll need to use a linker to create a suitable executable for the above platforms.

Answer (score 1):

An assembler and a linker, yes.

For linux, if you don't insist on the bytes, just copy the assembly code (stuff except the first two columns) into a file `foo.s` after a header line `.intel_syntax noprefix` then do `gcc -g -nostdlib -m32 foo.s` and you will get your executable `a.out` you can load into `gdb`.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
mov eax,0x0
mov ebx,0xbaaeb662
xor eax,ebx
mov ecx,0xc0ffee
mov edx,0xdeadbeef
cmp eax,0x31337
je loc_0000001f
jmp edx
loc_0000001f:
jmp ecx
```

Note that this code will jump to a different address which is not included in this paste, so it's pretty much useless. Also, it's brain-dead simple you hardly need to single step it at all. It's basically:

```
if (0 ^ 0xbaaeb662 == 0x31337) goto 0xc0ffee else goto 0xdeadbeef;
```

(I assume the zero is a placeholder.)

If you insist on using the raw machine code bytes, you can stick those into your `foo.s` with `.byte` directives like so:

```
.byte 0xb8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
.byte 0xbb, 0x62, 0xb6, 0xae, 0xba
```

You get the idea, I am not gonna type all these out.